# LibGDX Rectangle not Scaling to ImageButton Instance as Expected

Tags: java, libgdx

below is the class I wrote for a `GameButton`instance:

```
public class GameButton {

private ImageButton button;
private TextureRegionDrawable drawableUp, drawableDown;
private Rectangle hitbox;

public GameButton(int x, int y){
    final int boxSize = 100;
    drawableUp = new TextureRegionDrawable(AssetLoader.gameButtonUp);
    drawableDown = new TextureRegionDrawable(AssetLoader.gameButtonDown);
    button = new ImageButton(drawableDown, drawableUp, drawableUp);
    button.setPosition(x,y);
    button.setSize(100,100);
    hitbox = new Rectangle(x,y,0,0);

    button.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ChangeEvent event, Actor actor) {
            if(button.isChecked()){
                hitbox.setSize(boxSize,boxSize);
                Gdx.app.log("Button", "active ("+hitbox.getWidth()+","+hitbox.getHeight()+")");
            }else{
                hitbox.setSize(0,0);
                Gdx.app.log("Button", "inactive ("+hitbox.getWidth()+","+hitbox.getHeight()+")");
                button.setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    });
}

public Rectangle getHitbox(){ return hitbox; }

public ImageButton getButton(){return button;}}
```

Essentially this class defines an `ImageButton` with a bounding `Rectangle` that changes size whenever I click the button. The size change works as expected, however the bounding `Rectangle` isn't up to scale with the `ImageButton`. `AssetLoader.gameButtonUp` is a `TextureRegion` with coordinates `(131,142)` the same dimensions as the texture image.

However, when I use `ShapeRenderer` to draw where the rectangle is on screen I get this[image: big rectangle],

when the desired outcome to have that big square is to be on top of the blue button in this image and for it to be the same size

[image: no rectangle]

(Ignore the smaller rectangle in the top left)

I'm still new to libGDX, so any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Use button.setTransform(true);

Comment: That doesn't really do much. I want to have the Rectangle scaled and fit onto the leftmost blue button in the second image. It currently doesn't fit the size of the button